# How to create a subset of a dictionray from a variable number of keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, subset

I want to create a subset of a dictionary like this:

```py
key=['a','b','c']
val=[1,2,3]

dictex={k: val[i] for ind, k in enumerate (key)}
subdic={k: dictex[k] for k in ('a')}
print(subdic)
```

Out:

```
{'a': 3}
```

however when I do it with my dictionary it doesn't work.

Here is the list of keys I am using:

```py
key=list(tabledic.keys())
print (key)
```

Out:

```
['INTRO sheet',
 'Mo-G-development',
 'DIE-deposition-250nm',
 'Die-development-250nm',
 'Etching test',
 'Die-deposition-150nm',
 'Die-development-150nm',
 'Die-dev-day3-before-starting',
 'Die-development-day3',
 'dev semi',
 'deposition GIZO',
 'Deposition SD',
 'SD-development ']
```

And here is the code I am running:

```
#random list of values for dictionary
val=np.arange(len(key))
#create the dictionary

dictex={k: val[i] for ind, k in enumerate (key)}
subdic={k: dictex[k] for k in ('dev semi')}
print (subdic)
```

I get the following error:

```py
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-155-d062206ef3f4> in <module>()
      3 
      4 dictex={k: val[i] for ind, k in enumerate (key)}
----> 5 subdic={k: dictex[k] for k in ('dev semi')}
      6 subdic

<ipython-input-155-d062206ef3f4> in <dictcomp>(.0)
      3 
      4 dictex={k: val[i] for ind, k in enumerate (key)}
----> 5 subdic={k: dictex[k] for k in ('dev semi')}
      6 subdic

KeyError: 'd'
```

And when I run it like so:

```py
key=list(tabledic.keys())
val=np.arange(len(key))

dictex={k: val[i] for ind, k in enumerate (key)}
subdic={k: dictex[k] for k in ('dev semi', 'dev semi')}
print (subdic)
```

I get this output:

```py
{'dev semi': 2}
```

Why will it not run with one key?
Why am I getting only one output when I run it with 2 keys?

Comment: Can you add how `tabledic` looks like

Comment: `('dev semi')` is not a tuple, but `('dev semi',)` (note the extra comma) is. That's because parentheses around a string evaluates to a string.  You need commas for it to be a tuple. When you do `for k in ('dev semi')` it iterates over each letter in the string.

Comment: Note that `dictex={k: val[i] for ind, k in enumerate (key)}` is idiomatically written as `dictex = dict(zip(key, val))` and if `val` is never reused you don't need to give it a name `dictex = dict(zip(key, np.arange(len(key))))` or just `dictex = dict(zip(key, range(len(key))))`

Comment: Thanks, yeah that does look neater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that here:

```
subdic={k: dictex[k] for k in ('dev semi')}
```

`('dev demi')` needs to be a `tuple`, but in fact it's just a parenthesized string (since there's only one element).  For force a `tuple`, change it to:

```
subdic={k: dictex[k] for k in ('dev semi',)}
```

The comma after the item forces it to be a single-item tuple, so then `k` will take on the value of the entire string, rather than its individual characters.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
subdic={k: dictex[k] for k in ('dev semi')}
```

use

```
subdic={k: dictex[k] for k in ('dev semi',)}
```

So that it becomes a tuple of one element